# Convertir un dato entero a moneda con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo un template de thymeleaf que en un input recibe un dato entero que viene de un controller en spring, cuando se pinta el dato que llega se pinta así(ejemplo): `200000`, ese valor quiero que, en vez de que salga así, salga -> `200,000.00`.

Para eso estoy usando JQuery, para parsear ese dato y que se imprima como lo quiero; en la consola del navegador ya puedo imprimir el dato que quiero pero no sé cómo hacer que se vea igual que en la consola.

html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="miMeta"><small>Valor de tu meta</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control p17-input" data-field="miMeta" value="$25,000,000.00 MXN" id="miMeta" th:value="${fondo.tuNumero}">
</div>
```

y ocupo jquery para llamar el id para parsear el dato

```
$(function(){
   $("[data-field='miMeta']").ready(function() {
                    
      num=$("#miMeta").val();
      console.log(num);
      
      var numero = parseInt(num);
                     
      var formatoNumero = function(numero) {
          var cadena = numero.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
          return cadena.indexOf("-") != -1 ? "-$" + cadena.replace("-", "") : cadena;
      };

     console.log(formatoNumero(numero));
     var numeroSalida = formatoNumero(numero);

     console.log(numeroSalida);
     $("#miMeta").text(numeroSalida);

  });
});
```

Anexo imagen de cómo se debería ver el dato; ya puedo sacar el dato en la consola pero no puedo hacer que se vea igual en el input que dice *valor meta*, debería de verse igual que en la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el elemento con `id="miMeta"` es un `input`, y si quieres cambiar el valor de este tipo de elementos en jQuery tienes que usar `val()` no `text()`, que sería para cambiar el valor de elementos de texto como `<p>, <span>`, etc.

Así debería funcionar. Aquí muestra `NaN` porque ignoro su tienes algún framework para convertir el valor a un entero correcto que aquí queda fuera de alcance.

```js
$(function(){
   $("[data-field='miMeta']").ready(function() {
                    
      num=$("#miMeta").val();
      console.log(num);
      
      var numero = parseInt(num);
                     
      var formatoNumero = function(numero) {
          var cadena = numero.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
          return cadena.indexOf("-") != -1 ? "-$" + cadena.replace("-", "") : cadena;
      };

     console.log(formatoNumero(numero));
     var numeroSalida = formatoNumero(numero);

     console.log(numeroSalida);
     $("#miMeta").val(numeroSalida);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="miMeta"><small>Valor de tu meta</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control p17-input" data-field="miMeta" value="$25,000,000.00 MXN" id="miMeta" th:value="${fondo.tuNumero}">
</div>
```

Comment: Si me funciono, Muchas muchas gracias en verdad.